# Simplest way to design classic FSMs in Microsoft Visio?

Tags: microsoft-visio

I would like to create some basic Finite State Machines within Microsoft Visio. As an example, please take a look at the following:
[image: DFA Examples]
 *Image source: ["DFAexample" by Cepheus - Own work.](https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/File:DFAexample.svg#/media/File:DFAexample.svg)*

I tried to create my own stencil using simple ellipses, but the issue for me mainly lies in the styling of the connector curvature. The DFA example contains perfect arcs, but in order to achieve that I would have to manually adjust every connector. The state machine I am building is very large, so that isn't feasible.
Is there a faster way to do this?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I'm using Visio 2013. The version you are using is unclear.

When you create a new file in Visio select the template **Data flow diagram** as shown in the below picture.

[image: Data flow diagram]

In case if you do not find the template in your Visio, you can download it by using the *Search for online templates* search box. Search for *Data flow diagram*.

Comment: Thank you that works perfectly. I would have never thought to search for a data flow diagram.

Answer (score 1):

You can get to the Data Flow Diagram shapes by going to `More Shapes -> Software and Database -> Software -> Data Flow Diagram Shapes`.

[image: Data Flow Diagram Shape Selection]